# Access to a world from GUI system plugin for gzclient

Tags: gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a GUI system plugin that is loaded by `gzclient` in the following manner:

```
gzclient -g libgazebo_plugin.so
```

After `gzclient` starts I can see my world with simulation running. However I am unable to get access to that world from the plugin - `physics::get_world()` generates exception:

```
Error [Physics.cc:71] Unable to find world by name in physics::get_world[default]
```

Here how it is invoked:

```
void Init() {
  ...
  this->world_name_ = gui::get_world(); // returns "default"
  this->world_ = physics::get_world(this->world_name_);
  ...
}
```

`physics::get_world()` without arguments gives error "no worlds".

Any thoughts?

P.S. I actually just need to get simulation time (`world_->GetSimTime()`), so maybe there is another way?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2810/access-to-a-world-from-gui-system-plugin-for-gzclient/) by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Physics is done in the server, so the client has to subscribe to a published topic to get information about worlds and entities. You can use anything you see in `gztopic list`. The `~/world/stats` topic may be useful to you, though it is only published at 5 Hz. You could write a world plugin on the server side to publish time more frequently so that you could get it in a system plugin from the client.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-05-14**:
Great! Thanks!